# Codeigniter rest api route issue

Tags: php, json, api, codeigniter-3

I have create a simple rest api but when I hit the path in url it throw an error i.e. `{"status":false,"error":"Unknown method"}`. I was thinking that there is some problem in my `route.php` file. How can I solve this problem? Please help me.

controller: User.php

```
<?php
    require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';
    use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;
    class User extends REST_Controller 
    {
        function __construct() 
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();
        }
        function user_data() 
        {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('tbl_books');
            $sql = $this->db->get();
            $result = $sql->result_array();
            $this->response($result, 200);
        }

        function country()
        {
            echo "hello";
        }
    }
```

route.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'user';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
$route['user_data'] = "user/user_data";
$route['country'] = "user/country";
```

Comment: What is the route (Url) you are trying to call ?

Comment: `http://localhost/rest/user_data` @5eeker

Comment: but when I replace `user_data` to `index_get` then it works fine. what is the problem? @5eeker

Comment: I think that is happening because of your extended class, check the REST_Controller class if it has that method ?

Comment: I had already check `REST_Controller` @5eeker

Comment: On the controller, try to replace `user_data()` with `user_data_get()`, what is the output then?

Answer (score 1):

you need make 2 changes to your code as below,

1. change the method signature in your user controller,
   from  this function country() to this function country_get()
2. change route for country, you need to add method there.
   from this $route['country'] = "user/country";    to this $route['country']['get] = "user/country";

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you are calling

**http://localhost/rest/user_data**

Try calling

**http://localhost/rest/user/user_data**

In your case : It is trying to call User_data controller, and since it is not present it is giving you an error.

The first part after your **base_path** is the **controller name** followed by **method** of the controller.

http://localhost/rest/user_data

Eg :
http://localhost/rest/controller/controller_method

Refer :https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html